# Filling dynamically generated slection box with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```js
var addFilter = {
  "select": "--select--",
  "mcus": "Multi Company Use Case",
  "oc": "Order Condition",
  "ot": "Order Type",
  "dt": "Date&Time",
};

var multiCompanyUseCase = {
  "select": "--select--",
  "ags": "AGS",
  "agl": "AGL",
  "nafn": "NAFN",
};

var orderType = {
  "select": "--select--",
  "so": "Shadow Order",
  "co": "Customer Order",
};

function addToFilter(divName) {
  var val = document.getElementById('filter').value;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

  switch (val) {
    case 'mcus':
      newdiv.innerHTML = newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Multi company use case &nbsp: " +
        "&nbsp;<select id='mcuc_selection'>" +
        "</select>" +
        "&nbsp;&nbsp<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
        "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;
      break;

    case 'ot':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Order Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
        "&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='oc_selection'></select> &nbsp;" +
        "<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
        "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

    case 'dt':
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Date&Time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
        "<div id='startDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:165px; margin-top:-20px'>" +
        "<label>Start Date&Time: </label>" +
        "<input  id='date1' type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div id='endDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:550px; margin-top:-55px'>" +
        "<label>End Date&Time:&nbsp;</label>" +
        "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
        "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
        "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
        "</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "&nbsp;<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer; margin-left:780px; margin-top:-55px' class='remove-icon'><hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
      break;

  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
  if (val == "dt") {
    callDate();
  }
}


function callDate() {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });

  $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
}

$.each(addFilter, function(key, value) {
  $('#filter').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + addFilter[key] + '</option>');
});

$.each(multiCompanyUseCase, function(key, value) {
  $('#mcuc_selection').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + multiCompanyUseCase[key] + '</option>');
});

$.each(orderType, function(key, value) {
  $('#oc_selection').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + orderType[key] + '</option>');
});


$(document).on('click', '.container', function() {
  $(".remove-icon").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent(".container").remove();
  });
});

$(".remove-icon").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent(".container").remove();
}); < /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="flt" class="x_content">
  <br>
  <div id="div_filter1">
    <div id="div_filter2">
      Add Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
      <select id="filter"></select>
      &nbsp;
      <img id="add-icon" src="add-icon.jpg" alt="add" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addToFilter('div_filter1');">
      <button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
      <br>
      <hr style='width:1100px; margin-left:0px; margin-top: 20px;'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have generated the selection box on the basis of main selection box selected content and i needed to fill these dynamically generated selection box with json data. Although main static selection box is getting populated from the json data, but i am unable to populate these dynamic generated selection box.

Comment: I would be really appreciable if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function to populate the drop down once it has been created.

Your code tried to populate the drop down which was never created and jQuery was unable to find that drop down.

```
var addFilter = {
            "select": "--select--",
            "mcus": "Multi Company Use Case",
            "oc": "Order Condition",
            "ot": "Order Type",
            "dt": "Date&Time",
        };

        var multiCompanyUseCase = {
            "select": "--select--",
            "ags": "AGS",
            "agl": "AGL",
            "nafn": "NAFN",
        };

        var orderType = {
            "select": "--select--",
            "so": "Shadow Order",
            "co": "Customer Order",
        };

        function addToFilter(divName) {
            var val = document.getElementById('filter').value;
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

            switch (val) {
                case 'mcus':
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Multi company use case &nbsp: " +
                      "&nbsp;<select id='mcuc_selection'>" +
                      "</select>" +
                      "&nbsp;&nbsp<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
                      "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
                    break;

                case 'oc':
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Order Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
                      "&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='oc_selection'></select> &nbsp;" +
                      "<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove' onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer;' class='remove-icon'>" +
                      "<hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
                    break;

                case 'dt':
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<div class='container'>Date&Time&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:" +
                      "<div id='startDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:165px; margin-top:-20px'>" +
                      "<label>Start Date&Time: </label>" +
                      "<input  id='date1' type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
                      "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
                      "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
                      "</span>" +
                      "</div>" +
                      "<div id='endDate' class='input-append date' style='margin-left:550px; margin-top:-55px'>" +
                      "<label>End Date&Time:&nbsp;</label>" +
                      "<input type='text' style='width:200px; height:15%'></input>" +
                      "<span class='add-on' style='height:26px'>" +
                      "<i id='dateIcon1' data-time-icon='icon-time' data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></i>" +
                      "</span>" +
                      "</div>" +
                      "&nbsp;<img src='remove-icon.jpg' alt='remove'  onmouseover='' style='cursor: pointer; margin-left:780px; margin-top:-55px' class='remove-icon'><hr style='width:900px; margin-left:0px;'></div>";
                    break;

            }
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            if (val == "dt") {
                callDate();
            }
            else if (val == 'mcus')
            {
                $.each(multiCompanyUseCase, function (key, value) {
                    $('#mcuc_selection').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + multiCompanyUseCase[key] + '</option>');
                });
            }
            else if (val == 'oc') {
                $.each(orderType, function (key, value) {
                    $('#oc_selection').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + orderType[key] + '</option>');
                });
            }
        }


        function callDate() {
            $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
                language: 'en',
                pick12HourFormat: true
            });

            $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
                format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss PP',
                language: 'en',
                pick12HourFormat: true
            });

        }

        // populate on load.
        $.each(addFilter, function (key, value) {
            $('#filter').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + addFilter[key] + '</option>');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.container', function () {
            $(".remove-icon").on("click", function () {
                $(this).parent(".container").remove();
            });
        });

        $('#add-icon').on('click', function () {
            addToFilter('div_filter1');
        });

        $(".remove-icon").on("click", function () {
            $(this).parent(".container").remove();
        });


<div id="flt" class="x_content">
  <br/>
  <div id="div_filter1">
    <div id="div_filter2">
      Add Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
      <select id="filter"></select>
      &nbsp;
      <img id="add-icon" src="add-icon.jpg" alt="add" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"/> 
      <button id="go" type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
      <<br/>>
      <hr style='width:1100px; margin-left:0px; margin-top: 20px;'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working but by default its displaying blank space moreover it has added one more option as blank for the selection id ="mcuc_selection"

Comment: Yes, I fixed that, Thanks Varun, it really helped. :)